# center my image inside ul li div

Tags: html, css

I have placed a image in my footer and i want it to center but i wont work
I want my image centered so i hope someone can help me take a look at my code

HTML

```
<div class="center">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="centering_"></a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.center 
{
    width: 84px;    
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.center ul 
{
    width: 209px;
    line-height: normal;  

}
.center ul li 
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 11px;

}
.center ul li.last 
{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.center ul li a
{   
    display: block;
    height: 33px;
    width: 33px;
}

.centering_ {background: transparent url('../images/hello.png') no-repeat;}
```

EDIT:
Here is a example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XJbaM/

In my code i have two icons in my footer, what i want is remove the right icon en center de left icon in my footer, the text above the icons is already centered

SOLVED

Comment: Is it just a typo in your post here or is it that you forgot the `.` before `.centering_` ?

Comment: Can you please post this on jsfiddle or jsbin so we can see a working example?  Hard to tell what's a typo and what's not.

Comment: You want to center a anchor, not an image.

Comment: Create a duplicate example of your issue here http://jsfiddle.net/
It would be great effort to suggest solutions without more info

Comment: Check my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XJbaM/

Comment: There are 2 images there, you talked about single image being centered?

Comment: @MaartenVerstraten can you post of your desired result image what exactly do u need....

Comment: @shailenderarora no its already solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a wrapper div like this.

```
<div>
  <ul>
      <li>
          <div class="wrapper">
              <a href="img"></a>
          </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

and the css for wrapper:

```
.wrapper {
       margin:0 auto;
       width: /* how big your img is PX EM % etc */;
       text-align:center;
}
```

I TESTED THIS IN MY BROWSER AND IT WORKS.  HERE IS THE EXACT CODE I USED: A MIX OF YOURS AND MINE

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.center 
{
    width: 784px;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.center ul 
{
    width: 709px;
    line-height: normal;  

}
.center ul li 
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 11px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width:500px;

}
.wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:500px;
    text-align:center;
}
.center ul li.last 
{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.center ul li a
{   
    display:inline-block;
    height: 33px;
    width:100px;
}
.clear {
    clear:left;
}

.centering_ {background-image:url(img/activenav.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="center">
                <ul>
                    <li><div class="wrapper"><a href="#" target="_blank" class="centering_"></a></div></li>

                </ul>
            <div class="clear">ss</div>
            </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

NOW WHERES MY PIRATES BOOTY?

Comment: I forgot to add "text-align:center" to the wrapper div.

Comment: Hey Charles! Just wanted to say thank you for your solution. It definitely helped me center an image inside of a list item. Thanks!

Answer (score -5):

Place the tag < CENTER > and < /CENTER > around the whole div. It will center the div.

```
<CENTER>
<div class="center">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" target="_blank" class="centering_"></a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>  
</CENTER>
```

Comment: Let's encourage non-deprecated HTML shall we?

Comment: <CENTER> Is depreceated now