# Images are not Centralised (Just)

Tags: html, css, image

(Edit: I'm new to coding, so my apologies for stupid mistakes)

I can't find any errors in my coding, but my images are positioned slightly off-centre, to the right :( The images have been entered using a list format, but I'll just copy one image and then the relevant CSS:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="Images/mountains.jpg" target="new"><img src="Images/mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

(Updated) CSS:

```
li {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 40px;
}
```

I cant find what's wrong :(
Is it possible that my table is out of line? (Reference image in comments)

Comment: Where is the `nav` element? Also, `position: center` is not valid css.

Comment: I just added it in, I had it in the original HTML but didn't include it in the question. I didn't realise the position bit wasn't valid, what would be the alternative?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055393/center-image-using-text-align-center , see if it helps. Also, The first answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774074/center-my-image-inside-ul-li-div will probably work for you, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My ul element had some default padding, so I removed all padding in my universal selector.

It's always best practice to use reset css or normalize and then style your elements as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the commemt `position: center;` is not valid css.

To align to the center, give your li elements a text-align a center like:

```
li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It has "centralised" the image, so that may not be the thing that is off centre, it may be the table that I have above (I would post a screenshot but I don't have the points to do that ;-;)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or bin with a valid img url?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/EsUTwZA.png Here is the URL for a screenshot I took of the page

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

My `ul` element had some default padding, so I removed all padding in my universal selector.