# HTML: How do i center align an image inside an <li> tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I want to center an image inside a tag how do i do it? the image is placed on the extreme left on the screen but i want it to be in the center of the screen without sticking to the left. here is my html:

```
<div class="sequence-slider">
  <div id="sequence"><i class="sequence-prev icon-angle-left"></i> <i class="sequence-next icon-angle-right"></i>
    <ul class="sequence-canvas">

      <!-- Sequencejs Slider Single Item -->
      <li>

        <img class="main-image" src="photo/fac2.jpg" alt="Image" /> 

      </li>

      <!-- Sequencejs Slider Single Item -->
      <li>

        <img class="main-image" src="photo/fac1.jpg" alt="Image" /> 

      </li>

      <!THIS IMAGE STICK TO THE LEFT BUT I WANT IT IN THE CENTER>
      <li>
        <img class="main-image" src="photo/slide3.png" alt="Image" style ="width: auto;
  height : auto; " /> 

      </li>

    </ul>
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide corresponding CSS to know the problem better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [center my image inside ul li div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774074/center-my-image-inside-ul-li-div)

Comment: `li { text-align: center; }`

Comment: if you fiddle out your code, ican help you  better

Comment: text-align: center ofcourse.

Comment: oops @Turnip beats me to it :p

Comment: I dont want the text to be in the center i want the image to be in the center

Comment: @ShahidSarwar `text-align` will center your image too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.sequence-canvas, .sequence-canvas li {width: 100%;}
.sequence-canvas img {margin:0 auto;}
```

First line make sure the space takes full width.
Second line centers image in that space.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `text-align: center` to that`<li>`

```css
#sequence ul li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="sequence-slider">
  <div id="sequence"><i class="sequence-prev icon-angle-left"></i> <i class="sequence-next icon-angle-right"></i>
    <ul class="sequence-canvas">


      <!THIS IMAGE STICK TO THE LEFT BUT I WANT IT IN THE CENTER>
      <li>
        <img class="main-image" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/" alt="Image" style ="width: auto;
                                                                                                height : auto; " /> 

      </li>

    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have to use both your answer and @equi's answer to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Provide the full code to simplify the design

```
.sequence-slider{
  text-align:center;
}
```

check the below link

https://jsfiddle.net/a3pp2sea/

Answer (score 0):

You can just, just add `text-align: center` to your style attribute.

```
<li style="text-align: center">
    <img class="main-image" src="photo/slide3.png" alt="Image" style ="width:auto; height:auto;" /> 
</li>
```

Comment: That won't work. `text-align` needs to be set on an ancestor. Not the image.

Comment: Edited my answer, I guess now it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple means of achieving this, the first is the use of `text-align: center` on the parent element:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #ffa;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

While the above explicitly center-aligns the text, this works because the `<img>` element is an `inline-block` element, which will cause it to be centered exactly as any text, or `inline`, elements would be.

You could, instead, use a block-level `display` type along with the use of `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto;` for the `<img>`:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #ffa;
}
li img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li { 
 float:left;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
```